# Why is Google Chrome window opening in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I try opening a new google chrome window, it opens in visual studio code on ubuntu. How can I fix this? I'm not using any plugins. Sometimes if I restart, it works fine. But then sometimes, it isn't fixed even after restarting.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: in my case, this happens when I open the link from vscode with chrome position not yet open. So, the things you need to pay attention to are sure to open Chrome before clicking on the following link in the vs code.

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on when this worked for me